# Automatically create a summary of TextField

Tags: python, django, model

I am trying to create a summary field of a blog post object. I want the field to prepopulate based on the text entered into the TextField (text) above. For example, if I write a blog post 500 words long. I would like the summary field to pre populate with the first 100 words.

Please see below for my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    cover_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='coverphotos/')
    text = models.TextField()
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)
```

I looked into handling it like we handle URL slugs, but I can't find a way to get rid of the hyphens and place a max_length attribute on it.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the save method, and populate your summary field on save. This should make summary the first 100 characters of your text field.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    cover_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='coverphotos/')
    text = models.TextField()
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.text:
            self.summary = self.text[:100]
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```